# Is my laptop on Fire?

Tags: laptop, cpu, fan, temperature

During winter days my laptop is having cold with the result when I'm booting it in the morning the ventilator is making some noise for 30 minutes.

Today, however, it restarted around 4PM when I was at another location. When checking speedfan I found out there are some high temperatures (found out because of the sign).

Because I'm more a programmer and have no single knowledge about hardware I was wondering if it's really that my laptop is on fire.

Below 2 links with my laptop configuration and an image to the readings tab of speedfan.

[image: Speedfan]

[Computer Info](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?cc=us&lc=en&dlc=en&docname=c02932294)

Comment: What was running when these temperatures were detected?

Comment: 77 Deg C isn't that hot under load. My GPUs run about 100 Deg C 24/7 for the past 28 months with mining Bitcoins and Litecoins.

Comment: Are you using your notebook on a flat, hard surface? Or something soft and linty, like your pants or a blanket/pillow in bed? I ask, because of the vents on the bottom that need cool air to let itself breathe properly

Comment: @Ramhound firefox (with 2 tabs open) and speedfan itself.

Comment: As others point out.  You would know if your laptop was actually on fire.  If the fan is noisy it means its about to fail and you should replace it.  Your computer should not be this warm with only Firefox running.

Comment: @CanadianLuke my laptop is 9 out of 10 times on a stand next to a second screen. When its not on a stand, it's on hard and flat desk. Also the ventilator on the left side, not on the bottom.

Comment: @JeroenDeMeerleer I'm happy to hear that it's properly ventilated. I worked in a tech shop, and that was the number 1 cause of overheating in laptops, so I just wanted to check. Again, good job taking care of it! But yes, you will likely need to replace the fan, or possibly the entire heat exchange assembly, depending on the laptop

Comment: Have you ensured the intake and exhaust vents, as well as the heatsink and fan have been cleaned of dust and debris?

Comment: @techie007 I'm not sure about vents (didn't know there were 2 of them, honestly). There might be a problem about dust, since it has never been cleaned since i bought it about 3 years ago.

Comment: Well, get a screwdriver and a can of air, open 'er up and clean 'er out. :)

Comment: @techie007 My tech shop will do that tommorow. that will be more safe ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's highly unlikely your laptop is on fire and still functional.

The noise is probably a fan that has failed, or is about to fail. You should stop using it and take it to a local repair shop before it fails completely.

Comment: Modern CPUs will power off (or even slow down) when they get too hot.  This wasn't always the case, especially with AMD chips.

Batteries are something different, though.